# HTTP-DAV on IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7, http

I wan't to integrate [.NET Application Updater Component](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx) in my application for auto update of client application. It says

> The .NET Application Updater component
>   uses HTTP-DAV to download the
>   application update and thus requires a
>   Web server that supports HTTP-DAV. IIS
>   5.0 that comes with Windows 2000 and newer operating systems support
>   HTTP-DAV.

My server is a Windows 2008 Server and runs IIS 7.0. Does IIS 7.0 support "HTTP-DAV"? And if yes how can I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to configure [WebDAV](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/category/WebDAV.aspx) to get .NET Application Updater Component working.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2008 shipped without an in-box WebDAV implementation.

The IIS team released a WebDAV extension called [WebDAV 7.5](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDAV), which should work for most authoring purposes.

This is the same version of WebDAV that ships in 2008 R2. Use the Web Platform Installer to install it.